# How to delete rows which have the same values in only one column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delete-row

I have a Spark's DataFrame like this one below

```
*----------*-------*
|  Node ID | value |
*----------*-------*
|  Node 1  |   0   |
|  Node 2  |   1   |
|  Node 3  |   0   |
|  Node 2  |   0   |
*----------*-------*
```

Is there any way to detect only the same node ID values (e.g. Node 2 in the DataFrame above) in the Node ID column and delete the row of the same node ID values, even though these rows are different in the value column. 
For example, can I output a new DataFrame like this one below, in which the row of "NodeID=Node 2, value=1" will be deleted compared with the original one?

```
*----------*-------*
|  Node ID | value |
*----------*-------*
|  Node 1  |   0   |
|  Node 3  |   0   |
|  Node 2  |   0   |
*----------*-------*
```

Comment: SO, You want to keep data only having value 0 or is it ok to keep `Node2 with value 1` and deleting `Node 2 with value 0`?

Comment: Hi Saurabh. I don't care about the value, I just want to delete the old row with the same Node ID with the new one (e.g. Node 2 in this case).

Answer (score 2):

Try `Window` function with filter to achieve this

```
scala> var df = Seq(("Node 1" , 0),("Node 2" , 1),("Node 3",  0),("Node 2",  0)).toDF("NodeID","value")

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
scala> var win = Window.partitionBy("NodeID").orderBy("value")

scala> df.withColumn("result",row_number().over(win)).filter(col("result")<2).drop("result").orderBy("NodeId").show(9)
+------+-----+
|NodeID|value|
+------+-----+
|Node 1|    0|
|Node 2|    0|
|Node 3|    0|
+------+-----+
```

Filtering data based on row_number. which will help you to keep the number of records based on your requirements.